# JAGS error: negative length vectors are not allowed

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, rjags, r2jags

I am running a Bayesian model on a high performance computing cluster, and I keep running into the following error: "Negative length vectors are not allowed"

It occurs whether I run the model in parallel or not.

[error with rjags::run.jags -- parallel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXPGs.png)

[error with rjags::autorun.jags -- parallel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz9FU.png)

[error with R2jags::jags -- non parallel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4U8C.png)

I also get the error if I parallelize and run jags simply across the nodes.  I do not think the error is due to model specification or the data being fed to the model, as I have successfully run the model on a local r session (for a short MCMC run).

Has anybody run into this error before?
any help is greatly appreciated.  thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Negative+length+vectors+are+not+allowed suggests this might have to do with memory limits. Looking at the code that you're running might help someone identify points where you're using up memory.